# Hadoop + linux setup

Tags: linux, hadoop

After putting the following command:
`prateek@prateek-VirtualBox:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.3.0$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'`

I am facing the following error:

`bin/hadoop: line 133: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java: No such file or directory`

Comment: probably JAVA_HOME or other customization of Java's binaries location is not set correctly. Check this path first - does it point to Java?

Comment: Hi thanks for response  i checked java -version its giving correct path . i able to see java folder in given location but when i am trying cd java its giving there is no such directory..

Comment: What's the programming question here?